# Flickering of map in rviz (gmapping)

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[link text](https://youtu.be/heYHYjRZlRU) I am doing navigation on ROS, while in gmapping the map which is published is also flickering. Please check the given link so you will get rough idea. Is there any TF issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282579/flickering-of-map-in-rviz-(gmapping)/) by [rohanmore26](https://answers.ros.org/users/33615/rohanmore26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have multiple nodes publishing conflicting transforms between the odometry and map frames. You should run `roswtf` and `rosrun tf view_frames` , and see if either tool complains about multiple publishers for the same transform.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1